# The application compiled using pkg in Node.js does not recognize the files added to the project folder. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, requirejs

I need to be able to add new `.js` files to the `/public/bots` folder after compiling my project into an exe file using the pkg module. Upon launching the application, these new files should be detected, and specific functions should be imported from them. Could you please advise if this is achievable, and if so, how?

**Here is the code I am using. **
However, after compiling, Node.js does not recognize the added files in `/public/bots`

```
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/bots');

fs.readdir(directoryPath, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('reading eror', err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('files list:');
    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file);
        const filePath = directoryPath + '/' + file
        console.log(filePath)
        const module = require(filePath)
    });
});
```

When I run the project compilation using the code provided above, I receive the following warning:

```
Warning Cannot resolve 'filePath'
  C:\Users\Serg\Desktop\BOT\app.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
```

Comment: Potentially change it to a relative path, i.e. './public/bots'

Comment: @AidenCullo, I tried changing the path to a relative one, but the issue still persists.